# how can I find all applications which are binded to a certain windows hot key with java

Tags: java, windows, winapi

I tried to find some APIs but failed because there are too many windows API. Can someone give me some tips？

Comment: There is no API to identify registered hot keys. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I use Ctrl+Alt+S in Idea, a screenshot application also uses it which has a higher priority but I can't shut down that application. For that order, I want to write some code to detect how many applications are bound to one certain hotkey.

Comment: There are several different ways that applications can receive and react to hot keys. Even if you could get the list of applications that act on a given hot key (which you can't), what are you planning to do with that information? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I try to make a small program. When some applications have conflicts in one certain hotkey, I can quickly find who they are and determine which is needed and remove hotkey binding from other applications. So the problem is given a hotkey and return application list or process list related to this hotkey.

Comment: "*When some applications have conflicts in one certain hotkey, I can quickly find who they are*" - there is no API to do that. "*and remove hotkey binding from other applications*" - there is no way to do that outside of the apps that register hotkeys, only they know how to unregister properly. And that is assuming they are even using *registered* hotkeys at all (like I said, there are different way an app can detect a hotkey). "*So the problem is given a hotkey and return application list or process list related to this hotkey.*" - as I said earlier, there is no API to get such a list.